# Price groups configured on catalog not reflecting on products

Tags: umbraco-ucommerce

UCommerce 9.6.3

Added a new store with new Product Catalog with custom definition has default and allowed price group set to ES VAT

[image]
[image]

However the product in that catalog (in either of two categories) shows the wrong price group for the price edit

[image]
[image]

The old view shows no prices at all

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

When trying to add this SKU to a basket the error is

```
NullReferenceException: Unit price was not provided as a fixed value nor could it be calculated by PricingService, make sure that unit price can be calculated for product 'CONS-VAL' in price group 'UK VAT'."
```

So it seems that the price groups associated with the store, product catalog, or products are mixed up somehow.

Thanks Stuart